# Why are my Angular Material mat-grid-tile objects all empty?

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular.   I am having trouble getting an Angular Material mat-grid-tile to populate even though the parent mat-grid-list shows that it contains data (shown within Chrome Angular DevTools plugin)

https://github.com/djangofan/angular-book-catalog

In this snippet, the lines above the `<hr>` are displaying correctly but the app-kit items are all empty.

```
  <div>
    {{ kitList | json }}
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let kit of kitList">{{ kit.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px" gutterSize="16px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let kit of kitList">
      <app-kit [kit]="kit"></app-kit>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

Hoping someone can spot my error.   My project can be checked out if you want to run it.

Comment: Can you remove constructor block and check in kit.component.ts file?

Comment: Ok, you were on the right track.   My Input needed to be initi8alized to a default (not sure why when its value is being passed from the parent)  and the constructor needed to be a default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question since nobody else offered an answer.

Answer:  Turns out the constructor for Kit object wasn't correct, and so empty Kit objects were getting created.   The error message I got was really vague on this subject.